# Kindle Paperwhite (10th Gen.) not recognised on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb-drive, kindle

I am trying to connect my Kindle Paperwhite (10th Generation) to my computer running Ubuntu 18.04 via USB in order to transfer e-books. However, the device is not recognised by my computer.
Other mass storage devices work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff Those are settings for USB debugging capabilities and shouldn't be needed for basic MTP usage.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff I don't have a kindle fire. Paperwhite does not seem to have that option.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff It is actually the Amazon recommended way for people without wifi to download and transfer the files. So I don't think that is the reason here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Make sure the USB cable you are using isn't a cable designed only for charging. Sometimes USB cables that come with wall chargers don't actually have the pins/wires in them to make a data connection.
- Check that the Kindle is set to MTP mode if this is an option for your device instead of "Camera" or "Charge Only"

Comment: I am using the original cable for the device so I would be surprised if that is the case. I don't have another micro-usb device to test at the moment, so I will try this later.
There is no option like this as far as I can see.

Comment: I finally got my hands on a micro-usb cable which is able to transfer data and it indeed works! Thank you so much! Sill can't believe that Amazon sends out a chatge-only cable with its kindle.